# Java how do i declare a instance variable of another class if i need to pass a variable from the constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I want to create an instance of a class which requires currency for its
constructor, however i get the currency passed into the constructor of the class i am creating them in.

```
public class Owner_Class {
    
    
    

    Controller items = new Controller();
    private Item[][] list = items.getItemList();
    private String currency;
    private coinCollector dispenser = new coinCollector(currency);
    public Owner_Class(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;

    }
```

Whenever i run this the currency is just null. Is there anyway to do this or do i need to change how it works

Comment: Initialise `dispenser` in your constructor, where you have access to `currency`.

Comment: Why the Scanner? Delete extraneous code when posting here.

Comment: Will do sorry @BasilBourque

Comment: Whenever i do that @khelwood i no longer have access to it in my methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just.. shift the initialization to the constructor. Java first runs all 'initializing expressions', *then* the constructor. Hence, in your current code snippet, `currency` begins as `null`, then `new coinCollector(currency)` is executed (thus, passing `null`), then your constructor runs and sets `currency` - too late.

Hence:

```java
public class Owner_Class {
    Controller items = new Controller();
    private Item[][] list = items.getItemList();
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String currency;
    private coinCollector dispenser;

    public Owner_Class(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
        this.dispenser = new coinCollector(currency);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i access the coinCollector object from within my methods if i do it like this

Comment: nevermind my bad realised this works just didn't read it properly, Thanks!